# Can't access Application Context in Flask Socket IO

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

First and foremost, I am trying to create a 1 on 1 chat webpage.

In my view of the chat page, the url contains the username of the person i want to chat to, that's "http://domain.tld/chat/", i want to pass this username to the socket handler, so i could use the username as the room name and pass it to my emit and send functions.

So i created a new attribute for the g variable and assigned it the username in my chat view route and tried to access it from the socket handler, but it raises an error.

Clearly, i should be able to do it, since app context is made available to it as i see in the documentation. Is this right way or am i doing anything wrong.

Any help would be deeply appreciated

This is the error btw

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'current_chat'
```

My view function

```
@bp.route('/chat/<username>')
@login_required
def chat(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    g.current_chat = username
    return render_template('chat.html', user=user)
```

My socket handler

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message: ' + msg)
    socketio.send(msg, room=g.current_chat, include_self=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flask.g` object's life is a single request, or in the case of Flask-SocketIO a single event. You cannot use it to store data in a HTTP view function and expect the data will still be there in a Socket.IO event handler.

Try using the `request.session` to store your data instead.

Comment: Could you please explain more on your answer, could you give me the correct code that would work for me( i am still having trouble ) ?. Btw i have finished your Mega-Tutorial, its amazing, you are a great resource to the Flask Community. Thanks brother !

Comment: Ohke, finally i figured it out, using flask.session as a dictionary object. Thank you